# Javascript: regex for replace words inside text and not part of the words

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regex for replace words inside text and not part of the words.

My code that replace 'de' also when it’s part of the word:

```
str="de degree deep de";
output=str.replace(new RegExp('de','g'),''); 

output==" gree ep "
```

Output that I need: `" degree deep "`

What should be regex for get proper output?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
str.replace(/\bde\b/g, '');
```

Note that

```
RegExp('\\bde\\b','g')   // regex object constructor (takes a string as input)
```

and

```
/\bde\b/g                // regex literal notation, does not require \ escaping
```

are the same thing.

The `\b` denotes a "word boundary". A word boundary is defined as a position where a *word* character follows a *non-word* character, or vice versa. A word character is defined as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` in JavaScript.

*Start-of-string* and *end-of-string* positions can be word boundaries as well, as long as they are followed or preceded by a word character, respectively.

Be aware that the notion of a *word character* does not work very well outside the realm of the English language.

Answer (score 2):

```
str="de degree deep de";
output=str.replace(/\bde\b/g,'');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the reg ex `\bde\b`.

You can find a working sample [here](http://regexr.com?2t1vl).

The regex character `\b` act as a word separator. You can find more [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should enclose your search characters between `\b`:

```
str="de degree deep de";
output=str.replace(/\bde\b/g,'');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a word boundary as Arun & Tomalak note.

/\bde\b/g

or you can use a space

/de\s/g

http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html