# Limit Find and Replace to whole words google sheets .gs function

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a find and replace function, it replaces `every` instance of `aa` in a string, in VBA it would be `xlPart`

Is there a way to set the function so that it replaces `only` whole words or in VBA language `xlWhole`

Thanks

```
function FindReplaceWSHT(){

    replaceInSheet("Elements",'aa','ZZZ');
}

function replaceInSheet(shtName, to_replace, replace_with) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(shtName);

//get the current data range values as an array
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

//loop over the rows in the array
for(var row in values){

//use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value){
  return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with);
});

//replace the original row values with the replaced values
values[row] = replaced_values;
}

//write the updated values to the sheet
sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: adding a space before and after the search word doesn't work?

Comment: I thought like in VBA there would be a more formal way of doing this, something less prone to error.  Also if search word is entire cell content and also a substring then how to do this

Comment: Since gs is build from javascript ht eonly replace function is the one js. You could look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921701/javascript-regex-for-replace-words-inside-text-and-not-part-of-the-words?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript, so you could use the regular expression word delimiter `\b`.

Example:

```
function test(){
  var sheetName = 'Elements';
  var to_replace = 'aa';
  var replace_with = 'ZZZZ';
  replaceInSheet(sheetName,to_replace,replace_with);

}

function replaceInSheet(sheetName,to_replace,replace_with){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var output = [];
  for(var row in values){
    output.push([]);
    for(var col in values[row]){
      var value = values[row][col]
         .replace(new RegExp('\\b'+to_replace+'\\b','g'),replace_with);
      output[row].push(value);
    }
  }
  range.setValues(output);
}
```

### Test

#### Input

```
  |      A
--+----------
1 |aa
2 |bb aa ccZ
3 |aabbccZ
4 |bbaacc aa
5 |aaaaaaa
```

#### Output

```
  |      A
--+-------------
1 |ZZZZ
2 |bb ZZZZ ccZ
3 |aabbccZ
4 |bbaacc ZZZZ
5 |aaaaaaa
```

Comment: Ruben, thanks for this, is there a way to get it to match on `whole word only` as is it replaces substrings i.e aaa >> ZZZa I only want whole word aa >> ZZZ

Comment: @Tim : It works fine for me. I added input/output validation data to the answer. Consider to update your the question showing your adaptation.

Comment: Rubén, Thank you again, on further testing here is the issue.  If the `first` word in cell or if cell has only `one` word, then if  `aa` is a substring of word then `aa` gets turned into `ZZZZ`  e.g  `aaee` then I get `ZZZZee`  Otherwise it works

Comment: @Tim `aaee` is the equivalent to `aabbccZ` and to `aaaaaaa` from the test that I made. Did you made any change to my code? Could you create a demo spreadsheet and shared it?

Comment: Ruben, I closed then reopened my GS file and know everything is working!  Again THANK you for all the help